# Stereo versus Mono, Octave change? (Python)

Tags: python, pygame

So I have a program that can generate sound. I had it in mono, but I wanted to convert it to stereo to get some really cool stuff going on. However, when I tried to do that, the apparent pitch of anything I made was a whole octave higher.

```
import pygame.mixer, pygame.sndarray, time

def note(freq, len, amp=1, rate=44100):
    t = linspace(0,len,len*rate)
    data = sin(2*pi*freq*t)*amp
    return data.astype(int16) # two byte integers

pygame.mixer.init(44100,-16,2,4096)
pygame.mixer.init()
cleft=pygame.mixer.Channel(0)
cleft.set_volume(1,0)
cright=pygame.mixer.Channel(1)
cright.set_volume(0,1)

toneL = note(440,.1,amp=10000)
toneR = note(440,.1,amp=10000)
snd_outL=pygame.mixer.Sound(toneL)
snd_outR=pygame.mixer.Sound(toneR)
cleft.play(snd_outL)
cright.play(snd_outR)
```

The only change in the code above when I went from stereo to mono was:

```
pygame.mixer.init(44100,-16,2,4096)
```

The third argument (the 2) was a 1 before. This represents the whether to use 1 or two channels (hence, 1 means mono, 2 means stereo).

Does anyone know why simply changing the 1 to a 2 for the channel argument increases the pitch an octave? More importantly, how can I fix this (without obviously picking lower octave notes, I don't want to do that)?

Comment: Why do you call it twice? I'm not extremely familiar with pygame, but it seems unusual to do that.

Comment: When you double the wavelength of a sound wave, the pitch goes up by exactly one octave. No way that's a coincidence.

Comment: @Al.Sal So I can play it stereo. The amp argument in note controls how loud it is, so eventually I want to be able to control how loud the pitch is in either ear (if the user wears earphones). I haven't found any way to generate a pitch and control it's stereo spread.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense I don't double the sound wave. I just make the pygame expect stereo over mono. Also, I just learned it doesn't change by an octave, it's now only a couple steps.

Answer (score 0):

PyGame's [`mixer.init()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init) method has default arguments that are used when you call it a second time. The important one there is that the default sampling rate is 22050 instead of the 44100 that you wanted there.

Remove that second call & see what happens.

Comment: I'm afraid this changed nothing, but for referance, it now jumps a whole-step. (It sound like 494 versus 440)

Comment: But it does seem like messing with that may fix the problem.

Comment: Yea messing with that helped, but it only worked if I used it at pygame.mixer.init(22050,-16,2,1000). Why didn't I need it in the definition for note?